# iOS: How to animate multiple image layers using different blend modes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, jquery-animate, core-graphics, calayer

First the question: How can I (in iOS) create multiple layers from images using different blend modes and animate the images independently (not the rendered result).

I'm totally stuck with this. I want to draw some images and animate them a little bit. Just some rotating and scaling. The image layers should use blend modes like 'Color' or 'SoftLight'.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. CoreGraphics

draw everything and create an animation loop using CADisplayLink. The result was very bad performance, but it looked great :) Here's some of the code just to show how I use the blend modes:

```
    override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    let layer0 = UIImage(named:"ellipse_00")!
    layer0.draw(in: rect, blendMode: .screen, alpha: 0.5)

    let layer1 = UIImage(named:"ellipse_01")!
    layer1.draw(in: rect, blendMode: .softLight, alpha: 1)
    ...
```

as soon as there is a render loop that calls 'setNeedsDisplay()' the performance is gone. Even without changing positions of the images in the update method.

2. CALayers

With CALayers animations work perfectly, but the filters, compositeFilter and backgroundFilter still seem to be not supported in iOS 10 :(

```
    ellipse_00 = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
    ellipse_00.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    ellipse_00.isOpaque = false
    ellipse_00.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "ellipse_00")!.cgImage!
    ellipse_00.layer.opacity = 1
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIScreenBlendMode")
    ellipse_00.layer.compositingFilter = filter
    self.addSubview(ellipse_00)
```

3. [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

I could figure out how to draw the stuff correctly, but trying to animate something lead to random crashes and a lot of frustration.

```
    private override func setupUI() {
            super.setupUI()

            background_image = GPUImagePicture(cgImage: UIImage(named: "black")?.cgImage)
            ellipse_00_image = GPUImagePicture(cgImage: UIImage(named: "ellipse_00")?.cgImage)

            // Define Filters
            softLightFilter = GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter()

            // Define Filter Chain
            softLightFilter.addTarget(gpuImageView)

            // Process Images
            background_image?.addTarget(softLightFilter)
            ellipse_00_image?.addTarget(softLightFilter)    
    }

    override func updateUI() {
            super.updateUI()

            // Change position and rotate…
            background_image?.processImage()
            ellipse_00_image?.processImage()
    }
```

4. SpriteKit

This seemed to be the obvious way to animate 2D stuff. I managed to draw and animate the layers, but again the blend modes were not working. The Problem with SKEffectNode is that SKBlendMode is limited to a small subset and doesn't offer what I need.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. In this picture are 3 ellipses on a black background. The ellipses should be rotated and squeezed (which should generate a very organic effect if done right :P ). The blend modes are "add" and two times "soft light". This is just a part of a bigger thing I'm doing...

[image: result]

Comment: Could you upload pictures of what is happening and what outcome you want?

Comment: @Asdrubal ok added a picture...

Comment: I would take a look at the Accelerate Framework (specifically vImage). It might have the speeds you need. and still might allow you use the animations used in your CoreGraphics attempt
[programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/index.html)

Comment: @Asdrubal thanks for the suggestions :) I'll try and report my progress..